# C# Entity Framework code first can't add related data to a list of objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

This is probably a basic question but I'm struggling with this.
I have two classes: Owner and Pet:

```
public class Owner
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Pet> Pets { get; set; }        

}

public class Pet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }        

}

 private static void AddPet()
    {
        using (var context = new ZooContext())
        {
            var pet = new Pet()
            {
                Name = "Fluffy",
            };
            var owner = new Owner();
            owner.Pets = new List<Pet>();
            owner.Pets.Add(pet); //doesn't add new pet 
            context.Pets.Add(pet); //adding pet to Pet 
            context.Owners.Add(pet); // can't do this like this

            context.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
```

I'm trying to add the pet to both Pets and Owners context in my db, but the above code doesn't seem to be adding pet to the owner's list of pets.
Could you please advise what I'm doing wrong here?
Do I need to instantiate the list in a different way?

Comment: Shouldn't you do `context.Owners.Add(owner);`? And when you do that, see if that owner has the pet you just added.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. My mistake, thank you.